# Store frequency of different strings appearing in parent data's column, while considering range of numbers in its other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame whose first 3 rows look like this:

```
   white_rating   opening_short_name
0          1500         Slav Defense
1          1322  Nimzowitsch Defense
2          1496     King's Pawn Game
3          1439    Queen's Pawn Game
4          1523     Philidor Defense
...
```

and so on. Full DataFrame can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZJmlaf8Tu64vo08aih-p-jKMiFuLYVPKtoE299MFErA/edit?usp=sharing) (3*20,000).
Now, I want to know how opening values change in frequency as rating increases from around 700 to around 2700.

For that, I had created another DataFrame of the top 10 openings, since there are a lot of openings, and I was trying to get one DataFrame for each of these openings where I can get the frequency of the times it was played at each rating interval, such as 700-800, 1500-1600, and so on.

```
opening=data["opening_short_name"].value_counts().nlargest(10) #Top 10 openings
SG = data[data['opening_short_name']=='Scotch Game'][['white_rating']] #Scotch Game data
A=pd.DataFrame(SG[SG['white_rating']>900])
```

Above is an attempt at creating a range of data, but its obviously not able to get the frequency. Say, for 10 openings, and 20 intervals from 700 to 2700, it amounts to 10*20 DFs before I get proper data!

This is where I am stuck. I do not understand how to extract data for the number of times an opening appears, with the value of the cells being the frequency at which it appears *at each interval of 100 ratings*. I will then divide these vales with the number of all games played by players at that rating interval, to get a proper value of use factor.

The DataFrame I want is to help me create a histogram or an area chart showing the distribution.

This is how it should ideally look like, but with 10 openings' columns and the rows extending to all intervals to 2700-2800. Of course, the rows below are named to help make the idea clear, in practice, it needs to be named with the lower limit of rating:

```
             Queen's Gambit Italian Game Sicilian Defense
700-800               0.005         0.05            0.01
800-900                0.02          0.2            0.03
900-1000               0.09         0.05            0.04 
...
2700-2800              0.02         0.05            0.09
```

I think there can be a configuration of groupby(), sum(), iloc(). to achieve this, but I can't figure it out. I am new to pandas, so any help in figuring out the exact syntax will help. I have tried reading the pandas documentation, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to `apply` [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) after binning the data with [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('RO - RD.csv', index_col=0)

(df['opening_short_name']
 .groupby(pd.cut(df['white_rating'],
                 range(700, 3000, 100)))
 .apply(lambda s: s.value_counts(normalize=True))
 .unstack(1, fill_value=0)
)
```

(partial) output:

```
             Alekhine Defense  Alekhine Defense #2  Alekhine Defense #3  ...
white_rating                                                               
(700, 800]            0.000000             0.000000             0.000000   
(800, 900]            0.018868             0.000000             0.000000   
(900, 1000]           0.010582             0.000000             0.000000   
(1000, 1100]          0.027273             0.000000             0.000000   
(1100, 1200]          0.009825             0.000000             0.000000   
(1200, 1300]          0.014055             0.000000             0.000000   
(1300, 1400]          0.010160             0.000484             0.000000   
(1400, 1500]          0.010386             0.000325             0.000325   
(1500, 1600]          0.011136             0.000000             0.000000   
...
```

###### bonus: data visualization as [`clustermap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html)

```
import seaborn as sns

df2 = (
 df['opening_short_name']
 .groupby(pd.cut(df['white_rating'],
                 range(700, 3000, 100)))
 .apply(lambda s: s.value_counts(normalize=True))
 .unstack(1, fill_value=0)
)

sns.clustermap(df2, cmap='Greys')
```

on can clearly see that beginners and top players play very differently

output:
[image: clustermap]

Comment: `.apply(lambda s: s.value_counts(normalize=True))` -> `.value_counts(normalize=True)` ?

Comment: @jezrael no that's what I had initially done but this fails due to different size of the output (not all groups have all entries)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, it does look like they're very dissimilar in their choices.